# Несколько входов с одинаковым именем через POST в php

Tags: php, ajax, form, submit

Есть вот такая форма, которая фильтрует посты по id меток на `ajax`

```js
 var filter = $('#filter');
filter.submit(function(){
    
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(), // form data
        type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('.button-filter').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
        },
        success:function(data){
            filter.find('.button-filter').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
            $('#response').html(data); // insert data
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

```css
.filters_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.filters_list li {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.filters_el {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.filters_el span{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
}

.filters_el input{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.filters_el input:checked + span{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://test.loc/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter" class="filters_box">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
  <ul class="filters_list">
    <li class="filters_item"><label class="filters_el"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_tag_id[]" value="2"><span>tag1</span></label></li>
    <li class="filters_item"><label class="filters_el"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_tag_id[]" value="3"><span>tag2</span></label></li>
    <li class="filters_item"><label class="filters_el"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_tag_id[]" value="4"><span>tag3</span></label></li>
    <li class="filters_item"><label class="filters_el"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_tag_id[]" value="5"><span>tag4</span></label></li>
    <li class="filters_item"><label class="filters_el"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_tag_id[]"" value="6"><span>tag5</span></label></li>
    <li class="filters_item"><button class="btn_clearFilters" type="button">Clear Filters</button></li>
    <li class="filters_item"><button class="button-filter">Apply filter</button></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

При выборе нескольких чекбоксов, поскольку имена у них одинаковые, то запрос идет такого вида.

`action=myfilter&filter_tag_id%5B%5D=2&filter_tag_id%5B%5D=3`

Делал по совету который [тут описан](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php).

[image: test]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в `filter_tag_id` складывать через запятую значения? Возможно ли легко формировать массив из выбранных значений? (* был уверен что если значения `name` совпадают, то оно делает массив значений, но нет)

Comment: name у checkbox указывается как  `filter_tag_id[]` тогда будут отправляться в виде массива

Comment: Эмм, что-то не понимаю.  `<input type="checkbox" name="filter_tag_id[]" value="'. $cur_term->term_id .'">`  это ведь не отработает, оно просто заменит эти скобки.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите складывать значения через запятую, то вы можете добавить следующий JavaScript код:

```
  var form = document.getElementById("filter");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var tagIds = [];
  var checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    tagIds.push(checkboxes[i].value);
  }

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  input.setAttribute("name", "filter_tag_id");
  input.setAttribute("value", tagIds.join(","));
  form.appendChild(input);

  form.submit();
});
```

Этот код создает массив выбранных значений, которые соединяются через запятую, и добавляет новый элемент с типом hidden в форму с именем filter_tag_id и значением соединенных значений.

Comment: Может можете, объяснить почему предложенный вариант из stackoverflow не отрабатывает ? Возможно есть способ, без добавление стороннего элемента? * просто когда фильтром выбирают только одно значение checkbox `filter_tag_id` всё отрабатывает корректно.

Comment: У меня большое подозрение, что данный код заклинит все приложение, т.к. при событии **submit** вызывается функция, которая отменяет **submit**, а затем создает новое событие **submit**, которое вызовет опять же эту функцию и так по кругу.... Вы откуда этот ответ взяли? Вы его тестировали? Да и в вопросе отправка данных идет через ajax..

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitrii Sedov
Был прав, что бы забирать варианты массивом, достаточно что б у всех нужных `<input type="checkbox" name="filter_tag_id[]" value="3">` были одинаковые атрибуты `name="filter_tag_id[]"`

Тогда при передаче их на контроллер можно будет забрать эти значения через `$my_terms = $_POST['filter_tags_id'];` Проверил, работает.

Comment: был рад помочь =)